# Compile Error : Named argument not found - using Formula1:

Tags: excel, vba

I have created some vba code which i thought would work, but each time I run it I get a

> compile error: Named argument not found when using Formula1:

here is a copy of my code:

```
Sub Insert_Profile()

    ' Declare variables
    Dim MacroNames As Variant
    Dim ChosenMacro As Variant

    ' Define the list of macro names
    MacroNames = Array("X-Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large")

    ' Display the pop-up box with the macro names
    ChosenMacro = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select Profile Size", Title:="Profile Size List", Type:=8, Formula1:=Join(MacroNames, ","))

    
    ' Run the selected macro
    Select Case ChosenMacro
        Case "X-Small"
            Workings_Insert_XS_Profile
        Case "Small"
            Workings_Insert_S_Profile
        Case "Medium"
            Workings_Insert_M_Profile
        Case "Large"
            Workings_Insert_L_Profile
        Case "X-Large"
            Workings_Insert_XL_Profile
        Case Else
            ' Do nothing if no macro is selected or the selected macro does not exist
    End Select

End Sub
```

If I dont add the argument in, it brings up the blank popup box, so any help would be appreiated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox   There's no `Formula1` parameter, which explains the message you're getting. You're asking the user to pick a range object though: what are you trying to achieve by passing in a comma-delimited list ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I’m trying to get a pop up input box I’m macro and depending on what’s chosen it will then run another macro.

Comment: There's no way to use InputBox to show a drop-down list: you'd need to create a UserForm for that.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the info, I can get  it pop up, but the list is empty, back to the drawing board, I will try and work out how to do it using a user form, never done one of them before.